# Why isn't there ReadDirectoryChangesA?

Tags: windows, winapi

There is [ReadDirectoryChangesW](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365465%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in Winapis. But there is no ReadDirectoryChangesA.

Curious.
Why is it treated specially?
Is there anyone who knows the reason or history?

Answer (score 2):

It never existed in Win98/98/SE/Me. Many (most?) of the functions that have been NT-only from the beginning (e.g., the Net* API) are only available in "wide" versions (though in the case of Net*, they omitted the "W" suffix).

Comment: I don't think this is right.  There are many new APIs that have not existed in Win 9x that have both A and W versions.  And there is actually a good reason why there is no ReadDirectoryChangesA.

Comment: @John: I think your logic is flawed at best. The kernel is copying data into your buffer. Using (the kernel equivalent of) `WideCharToMultibyte` instead of a direct copy would be relatively trivial.

Comment: The kernel could, but that would be unprecedented.  It would also break existing drivers since it is actually file system drivers that implement this functionality.

Comment: @John: It wouldn't be unprecedented at all. In fact, essentially *all* the *A functions are nothing more than a thin wrapper around the equivalent *W function, that takes any input strings, converts them to Unicode, calls the *W function, then converts any Unicode results back to multibyte characters, and returns those to the caller. This has already been done hundreds (if not thousands) of times -- one more hardly qualifies as impossible.

Comment: Yes, the *A functions are wrappers, but they are implemented in user-mode and convert the output of synchronous API.   As far as I know, there is no native API (any Nt* function) that supports both Unicode and ASCII.

Comment: @John: As my wife would reply: "...and?" The answer in this case is: "yes, being asynchronous means it's not quite *identical*, but it is still *trivial*".

Answer (score 2):

The kernel internally is using unicode encoding.  Win32 APIs with W suffix usually translate to the internal NtXxx APIs.   The A version of the Win32 API needs to translate from ASCII to Unicode, call the W-version, and then translate any output back to ASCII.

In the case of ReadDirectoryChangesW the last part is impossible to do because the data is read directly from the file system to the caller's buffer, and potentially **after** the API returns so it is impossible to implement ReadDirectoryChangesA.

Comment: I wouldn't dare to say it's *impossible*. Might have worked with some kind of hook being installed. I'd rather assume MS considered it not worth the effort...